# Consider the following typographical error in the limit definition:...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Consider the following typographical error in the limit definition: $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0:x \in X, 0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \epsilon\Rightarrow \lvert f(x) – L \rvert \lt \delta$$ Show that $f$ satisfies this condition if and only if it is bounded on any bounded interval from center to. In the affirmative case, L can be any real number.

My answer

(→) Let $I$ be an interval of length $\epsilon$ and centered on $a$. Then $I \subset (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ and by the hypothesis, there is $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert -\lvert L \rvert \le \lvert f (x) – L \rvert \lt \delta$ for all $x \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$. So, for every $x \in I$ we have that $\lvert f(x)\rvert \lt \delta + \lvert L \rvert$ and consequently, $f$ is bounded on I.

(←) Let $\epsilon \gt 0$, There is $A \in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert \lt A$. Hence we have that for all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $\lvert x-a \rvert \lt\epsilon$ we have $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert + \lvert L \rvert \lt A + \lvert L \rvert$. Thus, taking $\delta = A + \lvert L \rvert$ we will have the condition we wanted and as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary the statement is proved.

It is acceptable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your title is really quite vague! To attract the right kind of attention from people who are interested in/able to answer your question, please use clearer, synoptic titles

Comment: But yes, your solution is correct in my judgement, and exactly as short as it needs to be